# ¿Cómo correr varias instrucciones dentro de un For en Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import os

paths = (os.path.join(root, filename)
         for root, _, filenames in os.walk('C:\\Datos\\') #ubicacion de los archivos a renombrar
         for filename in filenames)

for path in paths:
    newname = path.replace('_x_1', '_nuevo1') #se reemplaza el "_x_1" por "_nuevo1"
    print(newname)

    if newname != path:
        os.rename(path, newname)
```

lo que quiero es que dentro de ese mismo ciclo haga mas de una tarea por ejemplo que también haga lo siguiente:

```
newname = path.replace('_x_2', '_nuevo2') #se reemplaza el "_x_2" por "_nuevo2"
print(newname)

newname = path.replace('_x_3', '_nuevo3') #se reemplaza el "_x_3" por "_nuevo3"
print(newname)
```

Y así sucesivamente, ya intenté ponerlo todo dentro de ese ciclo y no funciona. Lo que hice fue hacer todo el código anterior para cada tarea en específico:

```
paths = (os.path.join(root, filename)
                for root, _, filenames in os.walk('C:\\Datos\\') #ubicacion de los archivos a renombrar
                for filename in filenames)

for path in paths:
    newname = path.replace('_x_2', '_nuevo2') #se reemplaza el "_x_1" por "_nuevo2"
    print(newname)

    if newname != path:
        os.rename(path, newname)
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo más sencillo que puedes hacer sin necesidad de usar el módulo [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) (para expresiones regulares) es anidar las llamadas a la función `replace`:

```
for path in paths:
    newname = path.replace(
        '_x_1', '_nuevo1'
    ).replace(
        '_x_2', '_nuevo2'
    ).replace(
        '_x_3', '_nuevo3'
    )
    if newname != path:
        os.rename(path, newname)
```

Con esto aseguras que si existe un `path` como `archivo__x_1__x_2__x_3.txt`, por ejemplo, obtengas lo que quieres. Si haces esto usando tu método:

```
for path in paths:
    newname = path.replace('_x_1', '_nuevo1')
    print newname
    newname = path.replace('_x_2', '_nuevo2')
    print newname
    newname = path.replace('_x_3', '_nuevo3')
    print newname
```

El resultado sería:

```
archivo__nuevo1__x_2__x_3.txt
archivo__x_1__nuevo2__x_3.txt
archivo__x_1__x_2__nuevo3.txt
```

Con la llamada al `replace` anidado:

```
for path in paths:
    newname = path.replace(
        '_x_1', '_nuevo1'
    ).replace(
        '_x_2', '_nuevo2'
    ).replace(
        '_x_3', '_nuevo3'
    )
    print newname
```

El resultado sería:

```
archivo__nuevo1__nuevo2__nuevo3.txt
```

### ¿Por qué sucede esto?

El problema con tu forma de hacerlo es que la función `replace` no modifica la cadena afectada, sino que retorna un objeto completamente nuevo:

```
>>> cadena = 'Hola'
>>> cadena
'Hola'
>>> cadena.replace('H', 'C')
'Cola'
>>> cadena
'Hola'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias , me sirvió de mucho tu explicación respecto anidar `replace`

Answer (score 2):

Supongo que con la explicación de César Bustíos era lo que buscabas.

Una alternativa mejor para lo que quieres sería usando expresiones regulares:

```
import re

rep = { 
    '_x_1':'_nuevo1',
    '_x_2':'_nuevo2',
    '_x_3':'_nuevo3',
}

pat = re.compile('|'.join(rep))

def subst(m): return rep[m.group(0)]

for path in paths:
    newpath = path.sub(subst, path)
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, como Houdini está teniendo problemas con funciones sencillas del string, me pareció que el módulo re se le iba a complicar un poco mas. +1 queda como referencia para futuros problemas similares